# Local resources via rdesktop not working

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy, rdesktop

I have raspberry pi with Raspbian “wheezy”. I am trying to rdesktop from pi to win 8. 
I use rdesktop 1.7.1. My problem is, that I can't share local resouce for ex. local folder.

```
rdesktop -u martin -r disk:pi=/home/pi/share <ip>
```

I can connect, login, work .... But when trying to access \tsclient\pi I get error: Win cannot access ....

I also tried chmor -r 777 for share folder

Thanks for any advice/help...

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest giving [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/) a try instead of rdesktop. FreeRDP supports NTLM & NLA as well as a number of other protocols within RDP that rdestkop does not. More details on their [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeRDP) page as well.

#### Feature List

- RemoteFX
- RemoteApp
- Clipboard Redirection
- MultimediaRedirection
- Disk Redirection
- Parallel Port Redirection
- Serial Port Redirection
- Printer Redirection
- Smartcard Redirection
- Sound Redirection
- Network Level Authentication (NLA)

#### Screenshot

[image: ss freerdp]

#### Examples

```
# connect using default RPP port (3389)
% xfreerdp mycomputer.mydom.com

# connect using different port
% xfreerdp mycomputer.mydom.com:1234

# connect using acct. + password
% xfreerdp mycomputer.mydom.com -t 1234 -u user -p password

# connect using acct. without password
% xfreerdp mycomputer.mydom.com -t 1234 -u user -p

# connect using domain acct. w/o password
% xfreerdp mycomputer.mydom.com -t 1234 -d mydom -u user -p

# connect to console
% xfreerdp mycomputer.mydom.com -t 1234 -d mydom -0 -u user -p
```